# What is this log, when I coded thread.stop()?

Tags: android, multithreading

```
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at spexco.hus.camera.Camera.cancel(Camera.java:273)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at spexco.hus.cepvizyon.ViewCam.onStop(ViewCam.java:83)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1169)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3797)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3416)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3487)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
10-18 10:26:39.382: ERROR/global(13919):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please ask a clear question in your post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's reasonably clear: `Thread.stop` is a deprecated API, and deprecated thread methods aren't supported in Android. Therefore it's throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

The answer is not to use `Thread.stop` - shut down your threads in a more graceful way, for example by setting a flag which the thread checks periodically.

Comment: How could you achieve that ? Where do you check the flag ?

Comment: @Dr Odissey: You check it within the worker task, whatever that's doing.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.stop()` is deprecated long ago.
Maybe `Thread.interrupt()` will help you, although it is not often necessary to do dirty things like that ;)