# android 2.3.3 not running on android 4.0.3

Tags: android

I'm developing an app that uses minSdkVersion=10 for gingerbread. it is working fine on all gingerbread devices but when I try to run it on 4.0.3 emulator(ICS) it always stops. is there any settings I need to adjust?

here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.das"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

and the error on logcat is this

```
  02-22 15:03:40.217: E/global(514): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
02-22 15:03:40.217: E/global(514): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
02-22 15:03:40.217: E/global(514):  at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
02-22 15:03:40.217: E/global(514):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1280)
02-22 15:03:40.217: E/global(514):  at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1247)
02-22 15:03:40.217: E/global(514):  at         com.example.SpelloGrande.splash$1.run(splash.java:48)
```

splash activity

```
public class splash extends Activity {

//how long until we go to the next activity
protected int _splashTime = 3000; 

private Thread splashTread;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    final splash sPlashScreen = this; 

    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    splashTread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                synchronized(this){

                        //duration
                        wait(_splashTime);

                }

            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            finally {
                finish();

                //start a new activity
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                stop();
            }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();
}

//Function that will handle the touch
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        synchronized(splashTread){
                splashTread.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Post splash.java:48 and surrounding code

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8686861/620338

Comment: there you go. I've seen on my java code the line 48 of my splash is stop(); which has a line through it and says `The method stop() from the type Thread is deprecated`

Answer (score 0):

You're using a method that is deprecated in 4.0.3, but not in 2.3.3. Basically 2.3.3 has the function but 4.0.3 does not. Whatever the function is that is on line 48 in Splash is the method you need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

In Android its better to use `Handler` for managing the `Thread` and `Runnables`

Create an Handler instance

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Create a Runnable thread

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("runnable started", "inside run");
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    };
```

And start the Runnable using Handler

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

And to stop the Runnable use

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: Try above thing I just found. And check that if its working or not and let me know. **I have just updated the Answare**

Answer (score 0):

Try use Runnable Thread instead

```
  splashThread = new Thread(new runnable(){
        public void run(){


        //do your things here


        }
  });
  splashThread.start();
```

**EDIT**

You don't have to include stop(); in your thread.
Your Thread will stop once it completed it tasks. Unless you use Thread.sleep();

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I already able to run it on ICS

Comment: you are welcome, try upvote or accept any one of the above answers if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

try below code, it work for me in all Android version.

```
public class Act_Splashscreen extends Activity
{
    private int delay = 5000;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        try
        {

            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Act_Splashscreen.this, newactivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            };

            timer.schedule(task, delay);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```