# Is it possible to replace the Android splash image with an html page?

Tags: android

Is it possible to replace the splash image with an html page in Android 2.2?

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
userIDPlugin=new UserIdPlugin();
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",60000);
```

Comment: What splash screen image?

Comment: the splash.png [logo image or loading image] image which is loaded before the app is loaded from res/ folder in my project folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452061/android-splash-screen) question. Just edit the splash.xml and put a WebView inside it.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, by replacing splash image with Webview with  in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can (following the advice of the other answers), but keep in mind that if the HTML is being pulled from the internet, the effect is that the user is going to start out staring at a blank screen for as long as it takes to load something... so you'll want to put another view on top of the web view or a progress dialog or something to give the user some indication of what's going on, and dismiss that when the page loads.

Comment: thanks,i have to place only static content with some style in the page