# Load screen while under async http request

Tags: java, android, httpwebrequest

On startup,  an async class is executed which scrapes a website for information. The screen is left blank during this time,  before the gathered information is populated to a listview. Is there any way to add a loading screen during this time?

I looked at this ([Add the loading screen in starting of the android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357226/add-the-loading-screen-in-starting-of-the-android-application)) but I don't think it's what I need because I don't know how long the request will take.

Thanks for your time.

After seeing some of the answers, I revised my code, but neither became visible. here is my xml file for activity main. there is also a textview layout xml file for the default textview element in a listview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="507dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the main activity's code:

```
    package adam.example.com.stockexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int index=-1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView ListStock= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final ArrayList<String>symbols= new ArrayList<String>();
        final ProgressBar pb= (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        List<StockElement> stats= new ArrayList<StockElement>();
        List<String> StringList= new ArrayList<String>();

        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("stocks.txt");

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                String []ret = stringBuilder.toString().split(",");

                for(int x=0;x<ret.length;x++){
                    symbols.add(ret[x]);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }


        for(int x=0;x<symbols.size();x++){
            stats.add(addStock(symbols.get(x)));
        }
        for(int x=0;x<stats.size();x++){
            StringList.add(stats.get(x).toString());
        }


        final ArrayAdapter<String> stockAdapter=
             new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.list_item_textview,
                    R.id.list_item_textview,
                    StringList);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ListStock.setAdapter(stockAdapter);

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you would like to delete this?")
                .setTitle("Warning")
                .setPositiveButton("No", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        stockAdapter.remove(stockAdapter.getItem(index));
                        symbols.remove(index);

                        WriteBack(symbols);

                        stockAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });


        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView

                TextView ItemText = (TextView) container;
                String selectedItemText=(String)ItemText.getText();
                String symbol =selectedItemText.substring(selectedItemText.indexOf(":")+1,selectedItemText.lastIndexOf(")"));

                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/finance?q="+symbol));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        };

        AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener itemLongClickListener= new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View container, final int position, long id){
                TextView ItemText= (TextView) container;
                String selectedItemText= (String) ItemText.getText();
                index=position;

                builder.show();
                return true;

            }
        };

        ListStock.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
        ListStock.setOnItemLongClickListener(itemLongClickListener);
    }

    public void WriteBack(ArrayList <String> list){
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("stocks.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            for(int x=0;x<list.size()-1;x++){
                outputStreamWriter.append(list.get(x)+",");
            }
            outputStreamWriter.append(list.get(list.size()-1));

            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public StockElement addStock(String sym){
        try {
            String s = new HTTPRequest().execute("http://www.google.com/finance?q="+sym).get();

            String symbol= s.substring(s.indexOf("<title>")+7,s.indexOf("</title>"));
            String name= symbol.substring(0,symbol.indexOf(":"));
            symbol=symbol.substring(symbol.indexOf(":")+2,symbol.indexOf(" quotes"));

            String price= s.substring(s.indexOf("<meta itemprop=\"price\"")+25,s.indexOf("<meta itemprop=\"price\"")+50);

            price= price.substring(price.indexOf("\"")+1,price.lastIndexOf("\""));

            String priceChange= s.substring(s.indexOf("<meta itemprop=\"priceChange\"")+36,s.indexOf("<meta itemprop=\"priceChange\"")+60);

            priceChange=priceChange.substring(priceChange.indexOf("\"")+1,priceChange.lastIndexOf("\""));

            String percent= s.substring(s.indexOf("<meta itemprop=\"priceChangePercent\"")+36,s.indexOf("<meta itemprop=\"priceChangePercent\"")+60);

            percent=percent.substring(percent.indexOf("\"")+1,percent.lastIndexOf("\""));

            return new StockElement(name,symbol,price,priceChange,percent);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `ProgresBar`(circle) in your activity's layout.And in order to set the loading circle right on the middle of the screen you can have your layout something like this.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@null" 
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/> 

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/> //to make it appear in the middle of screen
```

Now in your `Activity`

```
ProgressBar pb;
pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
```

Now when the task is in progress i.e when contacting your website, you can set `pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

And as soon as your task is complete just set 
`pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Edited my answer to show what I have tried. It stays invisible although looks fine in android studio's xml designer image.

Comment: In your layout,inside `ListView` add this line too `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`.And let me know if it's showing now.

Comment: Please post your `MainActivity`'s full code.I doubt that you are not using `pb.setVisibility` at the right place.

Comment: added whole main activity

Comment: Right now you're just making it invisible only.Initially you are making it visible but soon after you're making it invisible without performing your networking operations.I suggest you to use `AsynTask` to perform your networking operations like contacting to a website and gather information from there.Implement your code using `AsynTask`.`AsynTask` lets you know when the networking operations are completed so that you can do your stuffs which are required to be done only after successful completion of networking operations.

Comment: Thanks, although I dont think that is the issue. I used an AsynTask for the http request,             String s = new HTTPRequest().execute("http://www.google.com/finance?q="+sym).get();                     But Then I found that I can get the loading icon to show up, just not before the listview does. So, I believe that the asynctask isnt the problem, its actually taking that long to load the graphics to the screen for some reason. Would that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60488/discussion-between-sash-kp-and-adam-the-mediocre).

Answer (score 2):

Add a view to your XML that has some "Loading" message. Then use the [ListView.setEmptyView(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29) method to have the ListView control that view. It will be shown until the ListView is populated with items.

Comment: Tried this, I think it would work well, and add a lot of customization, but I am stilling having the same visibility issue as the progressbar. Thank you

Comment: It might be that you have the ProgressBar before the ListView in the XML. Try switching the order, the ListView might be covering the ProgressBar.