# Android displaying white screen until Asynctask starts but I have already loaded a layout

Tags: android, layout, android-asynctask, load-order

So I have the following code and a problem:
It should load a layout that should say "downloading database..." 
(dynamically added to the layout) however I get a white-screen until 
the database is updated and then it just proceeds with 
add_categories_layout(0) and works fine.

How do I get it to show me the first layout?

protected void onResume(){

```
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen_layout);
    SF = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SF);
    p_db_adapter = new DBAdapterProducts(getApplicationContext());
    c_db_adapter = new DBAdapterCategories(getApplicationContext());
    add_downloading_DB_layout();

    new UpdateDB().execute(CATEGORY_URL, PRODUCTS_URL, TIMESTAMP_URL_CATEGORIES, TIMESTAMP_URL_PRODUCTS);       
    while(DBupdated == false){}
    add_categories_layout(0);
```

}

Comment: I think this can be useful... I used once a similar approach.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452061/android-splash-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't draw the screen until onResume has finished, and onResume won't finish until DBUpdated is true (at which point the layouts are swapped).

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting `setContentView` in either `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`

Also can we see the dynamic adding of the layout?

Comment: Could you please post your add_downloading_DB_layout() function?

Comment: I've solved it: called add_categories_layout(0) in on onProgressUpdate and call in in onResume only if the db has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you set the contentview in the `oncreate()` method. There may be code in there causing it not no work. If you dont have on Oncreate method, make one and copy/paste this code in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `add_categories_layout(0);` in the `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask` since it runs on the `UI Thread`. So when your task finishes it will run this method and `onResume()` can finish doing what it needs. If your `AsyncTask` is an inner class then you will have access to the `Activity` methods and member variables. If it is a separate file then you just need to pass a reference of your `Activity` to it to call the method.

[Here are a couple answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a) that can help with it if you need.

As others have said, typically `setContentView()` is done in `onCreate()` to ensure it is one of the first things that runs but this shouldn't be a problem. However, I would move it there unless you have a reason to have it in `onResume()`.

Comment: Thanks but I never reach onPostExecute() because I want it running and updating every 'x' seconds. Do you think this is a good ideea? I use Thread.sleep(x).

Comment: Then you can put it in `onProgressUpdate()` which also runs on the `UI Thread`. Call `publishProgress()` in `doInBackground()` which will call `onProgressUpdate()`