# Android NullPointerException in Instrumentation.execStartActivity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, instrumentation

I keep getting the bellow exception from some users:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1414)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2880)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2986)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bb$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2535)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9130)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3826)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've found a similar problem [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5316) but it's not taken care of since April. All I know is that it was reproduced on a Samsung Galaxy Y (GT-S5360) and I'm using Google Maps Android API v2.

Do you have any idea how can I make a workaround for this?

Comment: Similar issue found on a Samsung GT I9500 (Galaxy S4) but on line 1416. Interestingly I'm also using Google Maps API v2 and have been receiving various errors relating to maps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have the same error, I also use Google Maps API. It seems to happen on all Android versions and phones. Just to mention few:

AN10DG3, GT-I8190, F815, GT-I9300, GOOPHONE, HTC One, KFTT, MID8127, KFAPWI, AN10DG3

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1409)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

as I read somewhere, solution is:

> Above mentioned problem can occur if you have emulator or device in which google play services are not installed. I don't have perfect solution but I figured out some work around to save your app from crashing. In this case you have to follow simple steps
>
> 1. Override startActivityForResult(intent, requestcode)
> 2. In startActivityForResult add super call super.startActivityForResult in try catch and catch the NullPointerException
>
> Easy its done Now you can trap the nullpointerexception here and add your error handling in catch

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    try {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // fixes Google Maps bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20905954/2075875
    }
}
```

Comment: Which class's startActivityForResult should be overrridden?

Comment: The one which extends Activity or FragmentActivity and crashes.

Comment: @steelbytes: some explenation? How do you know that this error is caused by com.android.vending ?

Comment: @Malachiasz: I was also experiencing this problem so I logged the value of intent during the catch and saw it was always com.android.vending (missing).  Since I only want to hide this exception when caused by MapView on phones without playservices/playstore, I added filter on intent.pkg as I don't want to hide other exceptions (eg, if my own code calls startActivityForResult)

Comment: @SteelBytes that's interesting, for me the `intent` was `null`. Malachiasz, might I suggest something though: instead of swallowing the `Exception` (which should only be `NPE`, btw.), it would be nicer to `onActivityResult(requestCode, RESULT_CANCELED, intent);`, because that code is very likely already handling the non-`RESULT_OK` case.

Answer (score 0):

in my case crash in Instrumentation.java

line 1581,

android.util.SeempLog.record_str(377, intent.toString());

intent is null then NPE

not sure how to fix this