# Stop handler in Android don't work

Tags: android, handler, runnable

i have this Handler:

```
private Runnable mRunnableReset = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        Log.i("MyApp", "mRunnableReset");
     }
};
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                mHandler.post(mRunnableReset);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I tried to use this code in my onDestroy() method

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnableReset);
mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

but the mRunnable is still running (i can see the log in LogCat).
If I use mRunnable.destroy() my app crashes.

How can i stop this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Thread.sleep()` use `postDelayed()` while posting your Runnable (instead of regular `post()`).

Answer (score 1):

Whoops you are using

```
while(true){
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 mHandler.post(mRunnableReset);
}
```

How will it stop then? It won't.

Instead it should be like,

```
private Runnable mRunnableReset = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        Log.i("MyApp", "mRunnableReset");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnableReset);
        mHandler.post(mRunnableReset);
     }
};
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                mHandler.post(mRunnableReset);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
    }
};
```

And then to stop your `mRunnableReset` use `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnableReset);`

And better would be using `mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnableReset, 2000)` instead of `Thread.sleep(2000);`

Also check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8686884/726863) to get complete working of how Handler will work.